# Why does angular material sometimes use [disabled][disabled]?

Tags: css, angular-material

I was styling the appearance of a disabled button using angular material. I found the CSS by copying the rules from chrome's Styles inspection tab that confused me looking like this:

```css
.mat-flat-button[disabled][disabled], 
.mat-raised-button[disabled][disabled] {
  // some css
}
```

Why are there 2x [disabled] and not just one?

Comment: maybe to increase the specificity

Comment: @TemaniAfif That indeed seems to be the case, it's seems to be a CSS hack when you need to be more specific than [disabled] and can't think of any other way.